Not able to execute pyautogui properly on Google-Colab as well as on Anaconda

I am using Google Colab on my OS- Windows and Chromebook.
Below is the simple code of pyautogui code, but still it's not executing properly.
As it runs properly, this code is on Anaconda (jupyter).

!pip install pyautogui

import pyautogui

#Move mouse pointer with 2 sec delay
pyautogui.moveTo(500, 500, duration=2)

Error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-db2179c13aca> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 import pyautogui
      2 
      3 #Move mouse pointer with 2 sec delay
      4 pyautogui.moveTo(500, 500, duration=2)

2 frames
/usr/lib/python3.10/os.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    678         except KeyError:
    679             # raise KeyError with the original key value
--> 680             raise KeyError(key) from None
    681         return self.decodevalue(value)
    682 

KeyError: 'DISPLAY'

image of the code and error


pyautogui is a package to enable interactions with your system's graphical user interface via Python. Jupyter via Anaconda or via Google Colab cannot access a system GUI as they are running in GUI's themselves and so it doesn't work from there. This seems like an XY Problem. What are you actually trying to do that you thought this was the solution? Note there are ways to a virtual linux GUI served by a Jupyter server to test/teach pyautogui use; however, I doubt that is what you are after.

Minor note: you should no longer be using an exclamation point with pip install in modern Jupyter. See more about the modern %pip install command here. The second paragraph here goes into more details about why the exclamation point may lead to issues. It was added to Google Colab, too, recently and so it is universal, working in JupyterLite as well.

Another way to think about your pyautogui wish is that both Google Colab and Jupyter run in your browser. That would be a huge potential security hole if code in a browser could automate controlling a sytem's graphical user interface. Browsers have inherently higher security restrictions than running Python from a command line of a system, which is where pyautogui is historically meant to be used.

If you could give me the required code changes, it would be helpful. @Wayne

"If you could give me the required code changes, it would be helpful." What do you mean by this? It seems you haven't read the main points I have expressed.

I read it, so you could tell me that I have to use "pyautogui" to do some tasks repeatedly. Open tabs and copy and paste to a Google Sheet. What would you suggest? And my "OS is Chromebook."

You should use Python and selenium to collect data and make a CSV or TSV that you then open with Google Sheets. I don't know if pyautogui works on a Chromebook because it predates that type of system. Can you run Python in a terminal on your Chromebook? If so, you can test it.

And you could possible use Linux desktop served via JupyterHub, like here to work with pyautogui on a remote machine. I think the link is in there for one. Let me know if you cannot fund it. I had long ago written up a demonstration of using the python webbrowser module in it to demonstrate using Python code to open a web browser, but that was a much older version of it.
